# Squares $n^2$ of the form $9<n^2 = \sum_{j=0}^k 2^{aj}$; $a$ an integer at least 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Are there perfect squares $n^2>9$ of the form $n^2=\sum_{j=0}^k 2^{aj}$, where $a$ is an integer at least 3? Yes indeed, 1 is a perfect square, and so is $9=1+8$, but what about any other examples.

When $a=1,2$ the answer is no, as all odd squares are 1 mod 8.

For $k=1, a > 3$ the answer is no for as well; if $1+2^a; a > 3$ were a square then it would be possible to write $1+2^a=1+j(j+2)$ so $2^a=j(j+2)$. This is clearly impossible for $a=4,5,\ldots$

Comment: Such a square must be a nicely spaced palindrome in binary; however according to https://oeis.org/A262595 and the linked article, as of 1972, it is not known whether there are infinitely many square palindromes in binary or not, and no more is known (for $N < 10^7$) that is of your form.

Comment: The answer is also no for $k = 2$, as $(2^a)^2 < 1 + 2^a + 2^{2a} < (1 + 2^a)^2$.

Comment: @player3236 This is a special kind of palindrome though, isn't it possible that the answer is known to be no?

Comment: You're right. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58697/a-geometric-series-equalling-a-power-of-an-integer has more information on this (the general Nagell--Ljunggren equation), and if I have not misread, the case for squares ($q=2$) have been solved. I'll keep the irrelevant comment above for context. I was redirected to the MO thread by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152530/finding-solutions-to-equation-of-the-form-1xx2-cdots-xm-yn. EDIT: I found https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177952/when-is-qk-1-q-1-a-perfect-square to be more specific to your case.

Comment: Thank you @player3236 for the reference....I am curious if there is an elementary proof of this